# Why not have a dark-background with a light text on Retrocomputing, as either an option, or default?

Tags: feature-request

Why not have a dark-background with a light text on Retrocomputing, as either an option, or default?

- I do get the impression most of the internet prefers dark text on a light background, only because of paper-pages in books ( origins ), however, that white-bakground was not Glowing-White from a backlight or LED's.
- I wonder whether these webpages cause more or less eye ache than paper-pages in books. This site involves alot of very intensive reading.
- Remember how most home retrocomputers had a darker-background with lighter text

Comment: Bookmarklet: `javascript:document.body.classList.add('theme-dark');`

Comment: I think yellow text on a blue background would be even better.

Answer (score 4):

There are no plans to extend the dark mode option to more sites.

The most recent discussion of this on the main meta is...
[Plans for dark mode for all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359739/236563)
There are staff comments below the question that give the current position.  Also, the question links to earlier discussions around the same topic.

So, don't hold your breath.

There are ways of creating your own dark mode.  There are a couple of scripts over on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/) that claim to do it for you, although I've not tried them.  For example...
https://stackapps.com/q/8053/32479

I believe some other SE sites have created similar tricks.  You could hunt around.